# AWS Cloudfront S3 Static website Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Cloudfront distribution setup in front of an S3 bucket.

My folder structure in this bucket is something like:

```
index.html
page1
 - index.html
page2
 - index.html
```

Now if I visit the site through the standard S3 static website endpoint everything works. I start on / and can click on links that refer to /page1/ and everything loads correctly.

But if I access it through the cloudfront distribution then I get access denied for all accesses like /page1/ -> if I manually type in /page1/index.html it works though.

My problem is that my website is statically generated and I cannot change the links to refer to /page1/index.html instead of /page1/

How do I allow these directory level accesses via cloudfront?

Comment: Did you configure the Origin to point to the Static Website endpoint (eg `MY-BUCKET.s3-website-region.amazonaws.com`) rather than just selecting the bucket itself? This might be useful: [Use CloudFront to serve a static website hosted on Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/)

Comment: No I selected the bucket - that was my mistake. Your answer pointed me into the right direction - I found this answer to solve my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59634922/how-do-i-serve-index-html-in-subfolders-with-s3-cloudfront

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at this. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-default-directory-indexes-in-amazon-s3-backed-amazon-cloudfront-origins-using-lambdaedge/.

Using Lambda@Edge, you can dynamically modify requests. For example, appending `/index.html`.